# Try no for - PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Galera como faço para usar o try no for? Quando ele cai no except e a pessoa digita uma string, ele da outro erro e encerra o programa, no while consigo usar normalmente. Tentei usar um laço de for com while, mas o programa não repete a opção que foi digitada a string mas vai para a proxima.

```
for k in range(1, 6):
    try:
        teste1 = float(input(f'test {k}: '))
        teste.append(teste1)
    except ValueError:
        print('Erro, tente novamente')
        teste1 = float(input(f'test {k}: '))
        teste.append(teste1)


print(teste)
```

Comment: para cada elemento do `for`, você precisa **repetir** **infinitas vezes** a pergunta até o usuário digitar corretamente. Use um `while` dentro do seu `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é inicializar a variável teste1 como string e verificar o tipo dela, caso o casting para float dê errado ele volta pra linha inicial do while, até a pessoa digitar algo válido

Aproveitando sua lógica:

```py
teste = []
for k in range(1, 6):
    teste1 = ''
    while type(teste1) != float:
        try:
            teste1 = float(input(f'test {k}: '))
            teste.append(teste1)
        except ValueError:
            print('Erro, tente novamente')

print(teste)
```